# pre and post actions to an existing class method

Tags: c#, inheritance, action, trace

I’m a novice in C# and I need help. 
I need to implement a series of wrappers for functions that will perform pre and post action besides the original method.

This is the way I currently do it (one function example):

```
class A
{
       public StreamWriter Writer;


       public bool Writeln(string textToWrite)//wrapper for Writer.write(string)
       {
              PreAction();
              this.Writer.Write(textToWrite);
              PostAction();
       }

}
```

Related scenarios are - tracing each function entry (so the signature of post and pre is void post() and iterating all the method parameters through reflection).

I need this to be done on numerous classes and functions- so wrapping each one would be tedious, also if they change I will need to reopen the code many times.
The only solution I can think of (instead of composition-see the attached code above)  is inheriting the StreamWriter and overriding the base method, but again for multiple classes and functions isn’t very pretty, can anyone think or know of a different way for doing that?

BR,
Mosh.

Comment: What you have described is a feature provided by various dynamic proxy libraries. The [Castle Project](http://www.castleproject.org/) has a good one that I have used before, but there are many others.

Comment: I'd try a functional approach:
`void Wrap<T>(Action<T> action, Action pre, Action post);`
But it help much for wrapping entire classes.

Comment: mike z: i was missing the name- dynamic proxy, now i can read more- Great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could write a wrapper class and either pass that to the constructor of any class you want to wrap the methods of, or have that class create the wrapper class itself.

It would still be rather fiddly, but it does let you put all the wrapper logic into one class.

An example will clarify. `class Demo` shows how you use the wrapper class. Also note that the wrapper class allows you to detect exceptions (while ensuring that the exceptions are still thrown).

Argument-checking logic omitted for brevity:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public sealed class Wrapper
    {
        public Wrapper(Action pre, Action<Exception> post)
        {
            _pre  = pre;
            _post = post;
        }

        public T Wrap<T>(Func<T> func)
        {
            try
            {
                _pre();
                T result = func();
                _post(null);
                return result;
            }

            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                _post(exception);
                throw;
            }
        }

        public void Wrap(Action action)
        {
            try
            {
                _pre();
                action();
                _post(null);
            }

            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                _post(exception);
                throw;
            }
        }

        private readonly Action _pre;
        private readonly Action<Exception> _post;
    }

    public sealed class Demo
    {
        public Demo(Wrapper wrapper)
        {
            _wrapper = wrapper;
        }

        public string Name()
        {
            return _wrapper.Wrap(() => "This is a name");
        }

        public void Write(string textToWrite)
        {
            _wrapper.Wrap(() => _writer.Write(textToWrite));
        }

        public void ThrowsException()
        {
            _wrapper.Wrap(() => {throw new InvalidOperationException("Test");});
        }

        private readonly Wrapper      _wrapper;
        private readonly StreamWriter _writer = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
    }

    sealed class Program
    {
        private void run()
        {
            var wrapper = new Wrapper
            (
                () => Console.WriteLine("Calling pre()"),
                ex => Console.WriteLine("Calling post(), exception = " + ((ex != null) ? ex.Message : "<none>"))
            );

            Demo demo = new Demo(wrapper);

            Console.WriteLine("Name = " + demo.Name());
            demo.Write("Some text to write");
            demo.ThrowsException();
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, just to be clear- in your solution i still to implement each function i want to wrap in the demo class, right?